# Principal Component Analysis of yield curve change

Tags: statistics, yield-curve, principal-components

Following pictures are the `Principal Component Analysis` for the yield curve change from

https://www.coursera.org/learn/interest-rate-models/lecture/ZHMM6/principal-component-analysis

Why is the first loading(factor) exactly the level; the second loading exactly the slope; etc?

And we can see John Hull's book `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives 9th` `page 514.` It's totally converse to the above statement. It knows the `loading` of each factor and maturity first, then use the variance of `factor score` to determine which factor is most important.

In John Hull's version actually I don't know how to directly observe the loading of a factor for a specific  yield, e.g the `slope factor of 2-year yield`?

So I really confuse here, which one is right in the real practice?

[image]

[image]

John Hull's book `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives 9th` `page 514:`
[image]

Comment: parallel shift, ‘‘twist’’ or change of slope, ‘‘bowing’’

Answer (score 5):

To put things in context, if $\{{\bf X}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a set of variables and $\{{\bf Y}_j\}_{j=1}^n$ denote the principal components of ${\bf X}$ then

$$
{\bf X}_j = \mu_j + \sum_{k=1}^n{\bf Y}_k A_{jk} \tag{1}
$$

where $\mu = \mathbb{E}[{\bf X}]$ and $A$ is the diagonal representation of the correlation matrix $\Sigma = \mathbb{C}{\rm ov}[{\bf X}]$. The whole point of PCA analysis is to truncate Eq. (1) to a given number of terms $k_\max \leq n$

$$
{\bf X}_j \approx \mu_j + \sum_{k=1}^{k_\max}{\bf Y}_k A_{jk} \tag{2}
$$

The smaller values of $k_\max$ contain most of the information required to re-construct the set of observations ${\bf X}$. You can roughly think of this as a Taylor expansion

$$
{\bf X}_j \approx \mu_j + {\bf Y}_1 \color{red}{A_{j1}} + {\bf Y}_2 \color{blue}{A_{j2}} + {\bf Y}_3 \color{orange}{A_{j3}} + \cdots \tag{3}
$$

where the coefficients of the expansion are $\color{red}{A_{j1}}$, $\color{blue}{A_{j2}}$, $\color{orange}{A_{j3}}$, $\cdots$. In this picture this coefficients would correspond to $0$-th, $1-$st, $2-$nd, $\cdots$ derivatives, so that you could call them

- $a_1 = \{\color{red}{A_{j1}}\}_j$ level
- $a_2 = \{\color{blue}{A_{j2}}\}_j$ slope
- $a_3 = \{\color{orange}{A_{j3}}\}_j$ curvature

Here's an example for the Swiss market

[image]

Comment: But in John Hull's book  `how to directly observe the loading  of slope factor of 2-year yield?`

Comment: @A.Oreo By estimating $A_{22}$

Comment: Could you show some details in $A_{*j}$ is exactly the $j$-derivatives of the yield curve? That's the essential part I don't understand. And why the `slope` is the second derivative but not the first derivative?

Comment: @A.Oreo I never said these are the derivatives of the yield curve

Comment: sorry, I may misunderstand here. Then it's the derivatives of what?

Comment: @A.Oreo I realize that what's is confusing you is the name. Remember that the eigenvalues associated with each $a_i$ decrease with $i$, so each successive term in Eq. (3) is less important in determining the value of ${\bf X}$. Is in that sense that you *could* think of this as an expansion, *similar* to a Taylor expansion. In that spirit you *could* label each term with an order of the derivative. *BUT* it is just a label, you are **not** actually taking derivatives

Comment: Notice that the blue line is practically constant at 0.3, the red line goes from negative at -0.4 to positive 0.4, the yellow line starts very negative at -0.4, goes very positive at 0.4 and then again negative about -0.4. When we multiply these coefficients by interest rates we get: the average interest rate (times 0.3), a slope or first derivative approximation, and second derivative like term (but very roughly, for an exact second derivative we would need [-0.4 0.8 -0.4]).

Comment: @AlexC how to obtain those lines from the market data of $y(t,T)?$

Comment: but if they are not the derivatives, then how to observe the loadings from market e.g $A_{22}?$ Even there is no definition of Slope(If the slope is really $\dfrac{\partial y(t,T)}{\partial T},$ then we can calculate from $y(t,T)$) Could you give some detail?

Comment: @caverac could you refer some books of the level, slope, twist moving of yield curve?

Comment: @A.Oreo You need historical data for $y(t,T)$, e.g. for the 2-year maturity yield. Define the variable $X^j(t) = y(t + \Delta t, t + \Delta t + \tau_j) - y(t,t+\tau_j)$, this is just to remove the tendency in the time series. Do this for all maturities, this will give you a set of variables $\{{\bf X}_i\}$ (one for maturity). Calculate the covariance of these variables $\Sigma = \mathbb{C}{\rm ov}[{\bf X}]$ and diagonalize this matrix as 
$$ \Sigma = A \Lambda A^{-1} $$ with $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix. 

**That's it**, each column of $A$ represents the loading (see my figure)

Comment: Can we  directly observe the `loading matrix` from market(don't use the `covariance matrix`)? I know the deduction of the `loading matrix` from the `covariance matrix,` but the problem is that in John Hull's book(see my update), he first has the `loading matrix`(seems observed from market directly), then calculate the percentage of first three factors. But actually, we can easily obtain this result from the largest three eigenvalues of  `covariance matrix.` Then I guess, we can directly observe the `loading matrix` from market.

Answer (score 4):

We can calculate the principal components by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix. The largest eigenvalue represents the largest variance, second largest eigenvalue the second largest variance etc.

By plotting the components of the eigenvectors we can identify them with, e.g., shifts, tilts, flexing and so on. For example for a yield curve we usually have that the first eigenvector has all components positive (parallel level shift), the second eigenvector has the first half of the components positive and the second half negative (slope tilt), the third eigenvector has the first third of the components positive, second third negative, and the last third positive (flexing).

It just happens that the largest variance comes from a parallel shift in the curve, the second largest variance comes from a tilt of the curve, and the third largest variance comes from a flexing of the curve. **It is not required to be so**, it is just the dynamics of the market that can be identified with the principal components.

Comment: sorry, suppose we know $y(t,t+2)$ for $-2<t<0,$ then how do we calculate its `slope`?(not calculating the eigenvector of second largest eigenvalue of covariance matrix)

Comment: The slope is along the yield curve between the different maturities at a fixed point in time. Let ${\tau_n}$ be the maturities along the curve at a fixed point in time $t$. The slope between maturities $\tau_i$ and $\tau_{i+1}$ is approximately just the difference $y(t,\tau_{i+1})-y(t,\tau_i)$. If you want to be more precise you have to fit a model curve, $y_{model}(t,\tau)$, to the points along the curve and take its derivative w.r.t. $\tau$.

Comment: pls see my update, and it comes back to the first question why does the second (thired) largest eigenvector correspond the first(second) derivative of $y(t,T)$ respect to $T.$ The representation of `equation 3` in  `caverac`'s answer seems not easy to show this relation.

Comment: @A.Oreo I will emphasize on this again: the loadings are **$\color{red}{NOT}$** derivatives of the yield curve, these are just labels. You can call them whatever colorful name you prefer and the method still works. For instance, call the second loading $\color{\red}{\text{not-the-slope}}$, and trust-me, your numbers will be the same